# System XML exception for rendering after upgrade

Tags: experience-editor, presentation, upgrade

We recently upgraded to `Sitecore 9.0 Update-1` from `Sitecore 8.2 update 2`.
When accessing one of the pages in `Experience Editor`, we get the following error for one of the renderings used for page banner:

```
   
> 10524 11:48:06 WARN  Could not find type in
> ReflectionUtil.CreateObject: Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.ContentDot
>     10524 11:48:06 WARN  Could not instantiate xsl control object (tag: 'sc:dot', assembly: 'Sitecore.Kernel', type:
> 'Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.ContentDot')
>     ManagedPoolThread #1 11:48:07 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
>     ManagedPoolThread #1 11:48:07 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units
> processed: )
>     10524 11:48:07 ERROR Failed to render rendering
>     Exception: System.Xml.XmlException
>     Message: The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name.
>     Source: System.Xml
>        at System.Xml.XmlConvert.VerifyNCName(String name, ExceptionType exceptionType)
>        at System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName.Verify()
>        at System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList.AddParam(String name, String namespaceUri, Object parameter)
>        at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.XsltRenderer.AddParameters(XsltArgumentList
> arguments)
>        at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.XsltRenderer.GetArguments()
>        at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.XsltRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
>        at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer
> renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
```

This rendering has personalization rules applied to it, but other renderings (with/without personalization) seems to work just fine.

**Edit:** Using personalisation, by default the rendering content is hidden and is shown only when a rule is true. Looking in the experience editor the issue comes when the default (hide) rule is shown. Selecting the other rule, the rendering works just fine.

Comment: Is this an XSLT rendering?

Comment: My understanding of this so far is that, when by default you try to hide a rendering using personalization, Sitecore places a hidden rendering in place of the current rendering. This issue comes when this rendering is getting rendered. One of the parameters being passed to it contains an invalid value, and that is where it fails.

Comment: @GeorgeChang, to answer your question, the rendering for which I get the error is a view rendering. It is the replacing hidden rendering which I believe is XSLT based.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. This was resolved by removing spaces in the field names of my rendering parameters.

### Sample

> **Input**
>
> 1. Rendering with configured personalization has a hidden state
> 2. The rendering has at least one rendering parameter with spaces in field name like **"Mobile Width"**
>
> **Output**
>
> Error Rendering Xslt: /xsl/system/webedit/hidden rendering.xslt: The ' ' character, >hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name.

### The simplest solution

> Get rid of spaces in the rendering parameters fields, like **"Mobile Width"** => **"MobileWidth"**

### Reason

If rendering has hidden state then sitecore displays Hidden Rendering located on the following path */sitecore/layout/Renderings/System/WebEdit/Hidden Rendering*.

The rendering is a Xsl rendering that's why an instance of XsltRender will be passed to the first argument of Render method of ExecuteRenderer processor and will be used in the following calls.

> at System.Xml.XmlConvert.VerifyNCName(String name, ExceptionType exceptionType)
> at System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName.Verify()
> at System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList.AddParam(String name, String namespaceUri, Object parameter)
> at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.XsltRenderer.AddParameters(XsltArgumentList arguments)
> at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.XsltRenderer.GetArguments()
> at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.XsltRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
> at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(**Renderer renderer**, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)

Then all necessary information is added to xslt argument list including data from each rendering parameter

> at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.XsltRenderer.AddParameters(XsltArgumentList arguments)

Before adding each key, it is checked that the name is a [valid NCName as recommended by the W3C Extended Markup Language](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#NCName). [It's cannot contain any whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6159003), that's why it throws an exception

> at System.Xml.XmlConvert.VerifyNCName(String name, ExceptionType exceptionType)

Answer (score 5):

Your issue may be in your `Sitecore.config` file. The `sc:dot` XSL rendering was deprecated in 8.2 but still had some references in the `Sitecore.config` file, specifically in the `sitecore/xslExtensions` and `sitecore/xslControls` nodes.

**Sitecore 8.2**

```
<xslExtensions>
    <extension mode="on" type="Sitecore.Xml.Xsl.XslHelper, Sitecore.Kernel" namespace="http://www.sitecore.net/sc" singleInstance="true" />
    <extension mode="on" type="Sitecore.MainUtil, Sitecore.Kernel" namespace="http://www.sitecore.net/util" singleInstance="true" />
    <extension mode="on" type="Sitecore.DateUtil, Sitecore.Kernel" namespace="http://www.sitecore.net/dateutil" singleInstance="true" />
    <extension mode="on" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentDot, Sitecore.Kernel" namespace="http://www.sitecore.net/dot" singleInstance="true" />
    <extension mode="on" type="Sitecore.Xml.Xsl.SqlHelper, Sitecore.Kernel" namespace="http://www.sitecore.net/sql" singleInstance="true" />
    <extension mode="on" type="Sitecore.StringUtil, Sitecore.Kernel" namespace="http://www.sitecore.net/stringutil" singleInstance="true" />
</xslExtensions>
<xslControls>
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:date" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.Date" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:dot" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.ContentDot" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:html" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.Html" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:image" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.Image" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:link" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.Link" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:memo" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.Memo" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:sec" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.Security" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:text" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.Text" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:wordstyle" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.WordStyle" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:enableSecurity" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.EnableSecurity" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:disableSecurity" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.DisableSecurity" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:editFrame" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.EditFrame" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
</xslControls>
```

**Sitecore 9.0.1**

```
<xslExtensions>
    <extension mode="on" type="Sitecore.Xml.Xsl.XslHelper, Sitecore.Kernel" namespace="http://www.sitecore.net/sc" singleInstance="true" />
    <extension mode="on" type="Sitecore.MainUtil, Sitecore.Kernel" namespace="http://www.sitecore.net/util" singleInstance="true" />
    <extension mode="on" type="Sitecore.DateUtil, Sitecore.Kernel" namespace="http://www.sitecore.net/dateutil" singleInstance="true" />
    <extension mode="on" type="Sitecore.Xml.Xsl.SqlHelper, Sitecore.Kernel" namespace="http://www.sitecore.net/sql" singleInstance="true" />
    <extension mode="on" type="Sitecore.StringUtil, Sitecore.Kernel" namespace="http://www.sitecore.net/stringutil" singleInstance="true" />
</xslExtensions>
<xslControls>
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:date" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.Date" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:dot" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.ContentDot" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:html" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.Html" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:image" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.Image" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:link" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.Link" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:memo" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.Memo" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:sec" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.Security" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:text" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.Text" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:wordstyle" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.WordStyle" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:enableSecurity" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.EnableSecurity" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:disableSecurity" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.DisableSecurity" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <control mode="on" tag="sc:editFrame" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.EditFrame" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
</xslControls>
```

You'll notice that the Sitecore 9 `xslExtensions` configuration node has had the `Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentDot` reference removed. This is because that class has been removed entirely from `Sitecore.Kernel.dll` where as it was only marked as deprecated in 8.2.

The first 2 warnings in your log snippet...

```
10524 11:48:06 WARN Could not find type in ReflectionUtil.CreateObject: Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.ContentDot`
10524 11:48:06 WARN Could not instantiate xsl control object (tag: 'sc:dot', assembly: 'Sitecore.Kernel', type: 'Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.ContentDot')
```

...actually shows up in a fresh install of 9.0.1! This is likely due to this line in `sitecore/xslControls`:

```
<control mode="on" tag="sc:dot" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.ContentDot" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
```

I'm guessing that if you want to get rid of that warning, you can remove this line as well since `Sitecore.Web.UI.XslControls.ContentDot` no longer exists.

I would double check to make sure that during your upgrade you have removed the line from `sitecore/xslExtensions` in your `Sitecore.config` file. It's also probably safe to remove the one in `sitecore/xslControls` as well.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the details. I tried removing the control from the config. The warnings are gone now, but the error is still there.

Comment: I am also getting same error. Could you please provide resolution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution (didn't test it yet): [https://markgibbons25.medium.com/personalisation-error-in-cm-on-hide-condition-51e919f1ca51#:~:text=Error%20Rendering%20Xslt%3A%20%2Fxsl%2F,characters%20in%20the%20field%20name](https://markgibbons25.medium.com/personalisation-error-in-cm-on-hide-condition-51e919f1ca51#:%7E:text=Error%20Rendering%20Xslt%3A%20%2Fxsl%2F,characters%20in%20the%20field%20name).